# Ethereum was withdrawn from my wallet to the wrong address

Tags: wallets, myetherwallet

Ethereum was withdrawn from my wallet to the wrong address.

I am using metamask and decentralized wallet application.

1. The keystore file is stored in Apple could storage.
2. Mnemonic did not use or save anything except when backing up.
3. The wrong address is said to be unknown to the decentralized application service.

What are the possibilities?

Comment: Was it sent from the dApp to an unknown address, or from your address to an unknown address?

Comment: dApp service said 'We can't found unknown address in our log storage", but it was sent unknown address. I want to find bug possibilities or experiences like it.